# how to increase scroll bar width when mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to increase my body scroll bar width using below code.

```
    <body class="expanScrollWidth">
<div>My page Content</div>
</body>
```

I tried to do this using below CSS class

```
.expanScrollWidth::-webkit-scrollbar:hover{
    width: 20px !important;
}
```

my second effort

```
  body::-webkit-scrollbar:hover{
    width: 20px !important;
}
```

both are not working. Can you help me to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It should work

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: blue;
}

/* Custom Webkit Scrollbar */
/* http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: red;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    width: 40px;
    /*background-color: red !important;*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    /*background-color: #efefef;*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    /*background-color: #666;*/
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" /></div>
```

Comment: I need to do this my page body .

Comment: Replace `div` with `body` or `expanScrollWidth`

Comment: But small issue. I need to do this only body scroll. When i put this all scroll bar sections works with this.. how i prevent this

Answer (score 1):

## Use ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover

[image]

Comment: .expandScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    width: 10px !important;
}

this is not working :(

Comment: Do you have a scroll effect ? I mean there should be some content

Comment: Try without ".expandScrollbar" just `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover`

Comment: Does the scrollbar even appear ?

Comment: yes scroll bar appear but hover not working

Comment: .expandScrollbar:not(:hover)::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px !important;
} 
i tried this solution. This is working well. but problem is when user hover out of the window, scroll bar expanded :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: .expandScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    width: 10px !important;
} 
not working :(